# Why do prime factors exist only till the square root of number?

Tags: prime-factoring

To find all the prime factors of a number we traverse from 2 to sqrt(number). What makes all the prime factors accommodated within sqrt(number)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: Factors come in pairs: x * y = num. Either x or y has to be less than, or equal to, the square root of the number, while the other factor is greater than or equal to the square root. You only need to find one factor to tell that the number is composite, so you only need to search from 2 to the square root (inclusive). That is guaranteed to find a factor of any composite number.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you express a number as `z = x*y`, either `x` or `y` has to be `<=sqrt(z)`, otherwise the product becomes greater than `z`
2. For all `(x,y)` pairs such that `z = x*y`, if you traverse `x` between `[2, sqrt(z)]`, you can cover all `y` by getting `z/x`

*"What makes all the prime factors accommodated within sqrt(number)"*. This fact is wrong, a simple counter example is `7` for `28`. By using the first two points however, when you test the divisibility of `4` (which is `<=sqrt(28))`, you get `7` by doing `28/4`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `c = a * b`. If `a | c`, then `b | c` i.e. `(c / a) | c`.

We leverage this fact to reduce the time complexity to find all the factors of a number.

For example, take the number 12.

- Square root of 12 is 3.46 approximately.
- 1 and 12 (the number itself) are already factors.
- So we can iterate from 2 until 3.
- Since `12 % 2` is 0, 2 is a factor and `12 / 2` = 6 is also a factor.
- `12 % 3` is 0, so 3 is a factor and `12 / 3` = 4 is also a factor.
- This way, we have found all the factors.

In a sense, we iterate till the multiplicative middle point which lies at the square root for a single number and leverage the above property.

To find all prime factors, we must iterate over prime numbers from 2 until square root of the number.